# How to fix when partition boots in safe mode but normal boot gets inaccessible boot device

Tags: boot, windows-11

I have win 11 partition on a 2nd drive that I want to boot.  I can boot it if I boot in "safe mode" but if I try a "normal" boot, it fails with INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE.  There is a similar partition on the 1st drive that boots (but it is an expired windows insider build that I want to retire and stop using).  Note that I have booted other partitions (win 10) from this drive.

Both drives are identical m.2 ssd drives.

[image: Here is a picture of the device manager screen when booted in safe mode]

I am sorry that I couldn't take a screen shot in safe mode.  The windows  snipping tool did nothing.  The relevant partition is listed as healthy, boot, page file, crash dump, and basic data partition.

I tried to compare that with running one of the working partition, without success.  The w11 insider partition won't let me run mmc at all, and the w10 partition which came on the laptop doesn't show the same info when I  attempt to use device manager.

BTW, I haven't done anything to the bios settings.  Although I would be willing to uninstall the disk driver from that partition and use the generic one, since I am not aware of using a custom one.  The laptop is  an off-the-shelf Lenovo p53.  I don't know how to do that though.

Ok, I was able to run diskmgmt.msc on thw w10 partition and it looked the same except that the relevant (80GB, w10 p53 orig) partition now has those flags (Boot et al) set for status.

Comment: What happens if you disconnect the 1st disk and boot only with the second one?

Comment: The disks are inside a laptop (Lenovo p53) which I am hesitant to open.

Comment: Don't do that in this case. Could you add to your post a complete screenshot of the Disk Management screen when booted in Safe mode?

Answer (score 1):

This error typically occurs, when the Windows drivers are loaded while system startup and the storage controller driver of Windows is taking over the control. — A wrong driver will not be able to access the disk.

As you managed to install Windows (though you had proper access to the disks while finishing the Windows installation and configuration), I think you changed the disk access mode in the BIOS settings.

**Solution 1:**
Boot into the BIOS and switch it back the storage controller settings to the original values that have been active during the Windows 11 installation.

**Solution 2:**
If you want to keep the current BIOS settings, you need to exchange the storage controller drivers.

Depending on your hardware it might be enough to uninstall the inappropriate drivers:

1. Boot to save mode and uninstall the current storage drivers.
2. Uninstall the custom storage driver set.
3. Reboot into normal Windows mode.

As the generic driver of Windows is able to boot into Windows Safe Mode this should now work for normal mode too, as there is no special driver available anymore and the generic driver should jump in.

When this works, you can install the appropriate drivers of the manufacturer. But remember, changing the access mode in the BIOS might bring you into trouble again. — So first uninstall these drivers if you intent to change the storage controller settings in the BIOS.